# clang-format how to ignore extern C?

Tags: clang-format

This is my current sample code

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

typedef enum 
{
  BUY = 1, 
  SELL = 2
} OrderAction_e; 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

After I run the clang format it is changing as below.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

  typedef enum 
  {
    BUY = 1, 
    SELL = 2
  } OrderAction_e; 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

It is adding an additional two spaces for all my functions and typedefs.

Is there an option which I can use to ignore the extern C braces so that, my code looks unchanged like the first version of code I pasted above.

Following is the clang version used in my company

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 3.4.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were using a later version of clang-format, you could get very close. But with 3.4.2, I don't think so.

With version 6.0.0, you can get very close, but it seems to be necessary to put the brace on the same line as the `extern "C"` in order to disable the indentation of the `extern "C"` section. Doing this requires using the `Custom` setting for `BreakBeforeBraces`. This behavior of disabling indenting the `extern "C"` block doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, but it does work for me.

Try modifying your `.clang-format` file to contain this:

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true # <-- You need this
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: false # <-- And this
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom # <-- And this
```

Note that there are a bunch of options there which you can leave however you normally set them. Only the values of `AfterEnum`, `AfterExternBlock`, and `BreakBeforeBraces` matter for this. See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) for more details about these settings.

If you don't already have a `.clang-format` file, you would start by doing `clang-format -dump-config > .clang-format` and then edit the file.